# VBA IDE Access 2010. File not found when trying to open the immediate window

Tags: ms-access, vba, ide, ms-access-2010

I have been programming visual basic for 20+ years. This problem appeared suddenly in Access 2010.

When I try to open immediate window, Locals window and Watch Windows I get the error message: File Not Found

I did have problems stating Access 2010. It would reinstall Office and then give me this error: "error 1907 could not register font". Normally i could just hit ignore 3 times, and then the program would start. I wanted to fix this problem, so after clicking ignore two times, I chose Cancel the last time. The installation progress bar went backward. I did a "SFC /SCANNOW" with no problems identified. I rebooted. Next time I got into Access VBA IDE I could not access either immediate, locals or watch windows. When trying, I get "File not found."

Since then, I have made a repair of Office 2010. I did update windows and restart several times. Nothing is working.

In Excel 2010 VBA IDE, the windows are not missing.

I use Windows 10. Office 2016 is also installed on this computer.

Comment: Do you also have Access 2016 installed as part of your Office 2016 install ?

Comment: Yes I do. Access 2016 VBA IDE got no problems showing immediate or other windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repairing Office 2010 was not enough. 
I had to remove Office 2010 completely and reinstalled it.

Comment: Beat me to it - that was going to be my next suggestion. I think you have to re-install 2010 after 2016 for it work properly. I just kept an older laptop running, as it was easier :)